# Including additional tasks in LINQ to SQL managed transaction

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I would like to include an additional step (send async. message via RabbitMQ) inside transaction that is managed by LINQ to SQL, like this:

1. Client code calls DataContext.SubmitChanges()
2. Transaction start
3. Database operations executed
4. Publish message
5. commit or rollback

Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: What kind of operation are you willing to perform? Maybe you should add a trigger on DB?

Comment: Operation is publish async. message.  Not keen on Triggers, would rather handle in app. layer.

Comment: You can try overriding `SubmitChanges` method within your context class, open a transaction, call `base.SubmitChanges()`, execute your logic and finally close the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Not in that order, but why not do this

2.Transaction start

1.Client code calls DataContext.SubmitChanges()

3.Database operations executed

4.Publish message

5.commit or rollback

Linq-2-sql will respect an open transaction. Or am I missing your point?